# Android: resize images on scroll in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I believe I need a `ScrollView` for this kind of behaviour. I have attempted to use a `CoordinatorLayout` but this causes a parallax of the images at the top, whereas the behaviour I would like would be like the below images:

[image]

[image]

The behaviour I would like is for the user to scroll down the page (increasing the amount of the view they can see at the bottom, in grey) and as they scroll, the images at the top (in red) decrease in size yet keep their aspect ratio.

The `CoordinatorLayout` parallaxing is not what I want, as all it does is parallax the images - it doesn't do any resizing as far as I'm aware.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: Modified the image and question

Comment: @JoshLaird, Are you able to achieve this?

Comment: Never figured it out! I think custom view would be the way to go unless there are libraries that achieve this that have come out in the past 2 years

Answer (score 0):

You can find many libraries regarding parallax `ScrollView`. Here are two libraries I've found already.

- [ParallaxScroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)
- [ParallaxScrollView](https://github.com/chrisjenx/ParallaxScrollView)

These are easy to implement. You just need to do something like this. It keeps the aspect ratio as well and will fulfill your need.

```
<se.jmvo.widget.ParallaxScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:backgroundView="@+id/imageView"
    app:scrollFactor="0.6"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    ...

</se.jmvo.widget.ParallaxScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom view to achieving the behaviour you want.